# Android Fragment and logical application design

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is more of a design question and how one would go about designing applications. I have been having fun with fragments, but one thing that doesn't make sense to me something like this:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        page = getArguments().getInt("someInt", 2);

        Button btnOne = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.one);

        btnOne.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String currentText = getScreen().getText().toString();
                currentText += "1";
                getScreen().setText(currentText);
            }
        });
    }

    // Inflate the view for the fragment based on layout XML
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.standard_calculator, container, false);
        return view;
    }


    /** Return the screen TextView object for manipulation
     * @return screen
     */
    public TextView getScreen() {
        return screen;
    }
```

Screen title are private variables in the class and this isn't the whole class, but just the part that I need to help my question. There are going to be at least 15 or so buttons that manipulate the screen and it doesn't feel like good practice to and put them all in the onCreate method, I was wondering whether it would be better design to have them in another class that let the methods in the fragment be more specific to the life-cycle of the fragment, although one can say that the buttons are used by the fragment and therefore should be part of the class. Perhaps an "initialising" method is needed.

I was hoping someone might be able to direct me to some design patterns or logical way of thinking about application design, it is quite different.

Many thanks.

Comment: Also I realise this would crash because I am referencing the view before it has been created...but sticking to the original point please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting them in the XML is less versatile than doing it in code. If you don't want to have XXX anonymous methods, you can make your own Fragment/Class implement View.onClickListener and implement the onClick method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(final View v) {
    if ( v.getId() == R.id.btn_logout ){
        // Do One Thing 
    } else if ( v.getId() == R.id.btn_about) {
        // Do Something Else
    } else if ( v.getId() == R.id.btn_shutdown) {
        // Or Maybe do this :)
    }
}
```

Then in your onViewCreated just assign each button with "this"

```
final someBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_logout);
someBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

That can be cleaner looking than a bunch of anonymous methods and you know you have your click listeners in one place.

Comment: this is much better, I have done this before in some other practice projects. It is probably the cleanest way andI didn't want to put them in the xml for the same reason you stated - it isn't versatile and I have faced some limitations whilst I have been trying different things out. Thank you for the answer :) much appreciated. EDIT: I also felt that it wasn't really good coupling to have onclick in the xml...but that's just me

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to initialize them all in the onCreate() method. In fact, you don't have to initialize them in java code at all. You could simply define them in xml and define an "onClick" property in your xml. The method that you set in "onClick" will be called for that button. It's one way to make your Activities cleaner.